# Does there exist a quadratic generalization of the continued fraction approximants?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $t$ be a real number and let $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ be its continued fraction approximants.  These have the property that $$ \left| t - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right| < \frac{1}{q_n q_{n+1}} $$

In other words, $t$ is an approximate solution to the equation $q_n x - p_n = 0$, with error $< \frac{1}{q_{n+1}}$.

Suppose $1,t,t^2$ are rationally independent.  Is there a sequences of triples of integers $(a_n,b_n,c_n)$ such that $a_n t^2 + b_n t + c_n$ tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity, and each triple $(a_n,b_n,c_n)$ is the *best* such choice of coefficients, in some sense?

Comment: Using a theorem by Schmidt and Davenport in 1967 we can show that for all $x \in (0,1)$ and infinitely many quadratic $\alpha$(with $a$ possibly equal to $0$) such that $|x-\alpha| \le \max(|a|,|b|,|c|)^{-3}$. The construction of these $\alpha$ though is an open problem to this day.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're not allowing $a_n = b_n = c_n = 0$.

Clearly yes, in some sense: if you restrict the possible $(a, b, c)$ in some way (e.g. a bound on $\max(|a|,|b|,|c|)$) that leaves finitely many possible choices, one of them must have the smallest value of $|at^2 + b t + c |$.

If, for example, you impose $a = b$, you're essentially approximating $t^2 + t$ by rationals, so by Hurwitz's theorem you can achieve $|a t^2 + a t + c| \le 1/(\sqrt{5} a)$.  Presumably you can do better by allowing $b \ne a$, but I don't know how much better.